# Find minimum time duration

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs, duration

I have an array of time duration strings as below, and would like to find the minimum time.

```
group = ["41:04", "54:50", "01:03:50"] // note this is mix of **mm:ss** and **HH:mm:ss**
```

I am using moment:

```
group.map(tid => moment.duration(tid,'hh:mm:ss').asSeconds());
```

but it interprets the first two elements as "**hh:mm**" instead of "**mm:ss**", and results in:

```
[147840, 197400, 3830]
```

However, the first element "41:04" is the shortest time duration.

Is there any way to get this right using moment? Or what is the best way to find the minimum time duration?

Note that if i concatenate zeros to the string by myself (ie, **00**:41:04), it will be correct.

Comment: `Note that if i concatenate zeros to the string by myself (ie, 00:41:04), it will be correct.`. Then why don't you do it? Rule 1 in sort/comparison: Every item must be of the same type.

Comment: It sounds like you already know the answer! Or you could just check the string length side your mapping function and pass a different pattern to moment if the string is only 5 characters instead of 8.

Comment: You could `replace` all the `:` with empty string, then use `parseInt` on the resulting string and then compare. But this feels like a hack

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the seconds elapsed using simple mathematics without using any libraries. 
For example;

```
41:04 = 41 * 60 + 04
01:03:50 = 01 * (60 ^ 2) + 03 * 60 + 50
```

Creating simple function to calculate `seconds elapsed`.

```
const getSeconds = str => {
  const sp = str.split(":");
  let sum = 0;
  sp.map((d, k) => {
    sum += Number(d) * 60 ** (sp.length - 1 - k);
  });
  return sum;
};
```

Now you could loop through your array to get the seconds.

```
const min = group.reduce((d, k) => {
  const a = getSeconds(d),
      b = getSeconds(k);
  return  a < b ? d : k; 
});
```

As a whole you could check out the code snippet below;

```js
const group = ["50:04","41:04", "54:50", "01:03:50"];
const getSeconds = str => {
  const sp = str.split(":");
  let sum = 0;
  sp.map((d, k) => {
    sum += Number(d) * 60 ** (sp.length - 1 - k);
  });
  return sum;
};

const min = group.reduce((d, k) => {
  const a = getSeconds(d),
      b = getSeconds(k);
  return  a < b ? d : k; 
});

console.log(min);
```

There might be more elegant solutions. But this is what I came up with. :D